# Jquery Ajax call to PHP don't give me any data back with dataType JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working everyday with ajax and php at work, so it's nothing new. But now i tried a little project at home and i can't get it to work. I really don't know what i have done wrong. I just select a value from a dropdown and press a Button. The button has a onclick to a function calles "showTable". It selects the value of the dropdown and send it via ajax call to my index.php where i do a simple select to my database and wanna return the results, so i can build a table with it. But my ajax call always go to the error case, even if the result of the select is correct.

If i console.log my error, it just says "parseerror" but the network part always says 200 ok

So, this is my function within my index.html...

```
<script>

    function showTable() {

        var coin = $('#selectCoin').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                act: 'showTable',
                'coin' : coin
            },
            success: function(data) {

                alert("ok")

            },
            error: function(request, error) {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this is my php part

```
if($_POST) {
    switch ($_POST["act"]) {

        case 'showTable':

            $token = $_POST["coin"];
            $token_buy = $token.'_buy';
            $token_sell = $token.'_sell';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $token_buy";
            $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array());
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo json_encode($result);

            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to update the composer and added the

```
"ext-json": "*"
```

Also i tried to remove the dataType Attribute from my ajax call. After that it don't get into the error case, but also i don't get my data from backend.

If i let me show the error with following function

```
error: function(jqXhr, status, error) {
   alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
}
```

It says:

parseerror: SyntaxError: unexpected token "<", "<!DOCTYPE"...is not valid JSON:  and continue with the whole html part in the error message

Comment: What do you see in Network tab for that request in response part?

Comment: And your SQL is open to SQLInjection

Comment: i the response shows me the whole html part of my index.html + a json object with my selected data from the database </html>[{"TRADE_ID":29433737,"DATUM":"2022-12-02","KURS":2.3364 ...

Comment: maybe it has something to do with my smartay engine? i use $smarty->display("index.html"); before my code for the ajax call

Comment: So most likely that's the reason, why would you do it?